# AKM DAC problem

Tags: dac, i2s, pcm

I’ve been developing the basis for a granular synth and general digital development platform for the past few months. I was using STM32 chips at first, but I’ve switched to bare metal Raspberry Pi for development because it’s faster and simpler.

Anyways, I’ve been working the last two days on interfacing with an AKM 32bit DAC and I’m having issues troubleshooting. I am communicating with PCM data over the Raspberry Pi I2S peripheral. The DAC is an AK4414EQ ([data sheet](https://www.verical.com/datasheet/akm-semiconductor-data-acquisition---dac-AK4414EQ-899973.pdf)).

The problem is that there is no audio or signal coming out of any of the channels. The I2S data is coming through fine on my scope and logic analyzer. I’ve read all the voltages on all the pins and they are correct according to the data sheet. I should at least be getting some AC signal out of the DAC because it has proper clocks and data lines, but there is nothing coming out. I’m wondering at this point if the jumper cables have too much capacitance or something, but it seems unlikely that that would have such a negative effect.

If anyone has experience with this DAC, other AKM DACs, or just interfacing with external peripherals in general, any troubleshooting hints would be much appreciated. I can send pictures as well if needed.

Comment: There is significant amount of info missing. Maybe a schematic would explain more if you could provide one, as some of the missing info can be determined from the shematics. What mode you use, the hardware mode, or are you using software mode and reading and writing the DAC registers? Do you provide the Master Clock to DAC?

Comment: Add test pins on Rx to test with short leads (1cm) with 10:1 probe.  Ensure GND and supply’s are solid between  units.  beware of CM DC converters that are floating and consider RF cap to gnd or wire to 0V